# Each time I create a new virtualenv - I have to update Pip

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, virtualenv

I am using `Python 3.6` on windows.  Everytime I create a new virtual environment, I have to upgrade `pip` to the latest version.

I am just wandering if there is a way to upgrade pip (and any other componant) globally so that these components are the latest version when I create a new virtual environment.

Comment: Kinda surprised there's not an answer to this. I would think that the issue is it's deployed with python3 itself, but still annoying nonetheless.